# Store procedures using Apache camel

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, apache-camel

I am trying to call a stored procedure in an Oracle 11g database from Apache Camel. When I try to run my Camel context it is neither showing any errors nor getting any output from it. Please help me in resolving the issue.

I am calling my database and Java bean from the Camel context, I am passing the parameters to stored procedures from Camel context. The Camel context is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
                           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <bean id="oracleDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe"/>
        <property name="username" value="system"/>
        <property name="password" value="sys"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="functionWithNoParams" class="com.quephird.camel.component.StoredProcedureBean">
        <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource"/>
        <constructor-arg name="storedProcedureName" value="meaning_of_the_universe"/>
        <constructor-arg name="isFunction" value="true"/>
        <constructor-arg name="parameters">
            <list>
                <map>
                    <entry key="name" value="foo"/>
                    <entry key="mode" value="out"/>
                    <entry key="type" value="integer"/>
                </map>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="functionWithOneParam" class="com.quephird.camel.component.StoredProcedureBean">
        <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource"/>
        <constructor-arg name="storedProcedureName" value="greeting"/>
        <constructor-arg name="isFunction" value="true"/>
        <constructor-arg name="parameters">
            <list>
                <map>
                    <entry key="name" value="foo"/>
                    <entry key="mode" value="out"/>
                    <entry key="type" value="varchar"/>
                </map>
                <map>
                    <entry key="name" value="name"/>
                    <entry key="mode" value="in"/>
                    <entry key="type" value="varchar"/>
                </map>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="procedureWithOneOutParam" class="com.quephird.camel.component.StoredProcedureBean">
        <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource"/>
        <constructor-arg name="storedProcedureName" value="sum_two_numbers"/>
        <constructor-arg name="isFunction" value="false"/>
        <constructor-arg name="parameters">
            <list>
                <map>
                    <entry key="name" value="a"/>
                    <entry key="mode" value="in"/>
                    <entry key="type" value="integer"/>
                </map>
                <map>
                    <entry key="name" value="b"/>
                    <entry key="mode" value="in"/>
                    <entry key="type" value="integer"/>
                </map>
                <map>
                    <entry key="name" value="c"/>
                    <entry key="mode" value="out"/>
                    <entry key="type" value="integer"/>
                </map>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="procedureWithMultipleOutParams" class="com.quephird.camel.component.StoredProcedureBean">
        <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource"/>
        <constructor-arg name="storedProcedureName" value="sum_and_diff_of_two_numbers"/>
        <constructor-arg name="isFunction" value="false"/>
        <constructor-arg name="parameters">
            <list>
                <map>
                    <entry key="name" value="a"/>
                    <entry key="mode" value="in"/>
                    <entry key="type" value="integer"/>
                </map>
                <map>
                    <entry key="name" value="b"/>
                    <entry key="mode" value="in"/>
                    <entry key="type" value="integer"/>
                </map>
                <map>
                    <entry key="name" value="c"/>
                    <entry key="mode" value="out"/>
                    <entry key="type" value="integer"/>
                </map>
                <map>
                    <entry key="name" value="d"/>
                    <entry key="mode" value="out"/>
                    <entry key="type" value="integer"/>
                </map>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <route id="callFunctionWithNoParams">
            <from uri="timer://kickoff?period=1000"/>
            <to uri="bean:functionWithNoParams"/>
            <log message="${body}"/>
        </route>

         <route id="callFunctionWithOneParam">
            <from uri="timer://kickoff?period=1000"/>
            <setHeader headerName="name">
                <constant>Dan</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="bean:functionWithOneParam"/>
            <log message="${body}"/>
        </route>

        <route id="callProcedureWithOneOutParam">
            <from uri="timer://kickoff?period=1000"/>
            <setHeader headerName="a">
                <constant>35</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="b">
                <constant>7</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="bean:procedureWithOneOutParam"/>
            <log message="${body}"/>
        </route>


        <route id="callProcedureWithMultipleOutParams">
            <from uri="timer://kickoff?period=1000"/>
            <setHeader headerName="a">
                <constant>35</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="b">
                <constant>7</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="bean:procedureWithMultipleOutParams"/>
            <log message="${body}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

I am using Java class for passing the parameters to store procedure in database:

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Handler;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlInOutParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;

import org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This bean can be used in an Apache Camel route,
 * and can be configured to invoke a stored procedure.
 */
public class StoredProcedureBean extends StoredProcedure {
    private final static String PARAMETER_MODE_IN = "in";
    private final static String PARAMETER_MODE_OUT = "out";
    private final static String PARAMETER_MODE_INOUT = "inout";

    private Set<String> inParameterNames = new HashSet<String>();

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param dataSource
     * @param storedProcedureName
     * @param isFunction
     * @param parameters
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public StoredProcedureBean(final DataSource dataSource,
                               final String storedProcedureName,
                               final boolean isFunction,
                               final List<Map<String, String>> parameters) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        setDataSource(dataSource);
        setSql(storedProcedureName);
        setFunction(isFunction);

        // Iterate over all of the stored procedure parameters...
        for (Map<String, String> parameter : parameters ) {
            String parameterName = parameter.get("name");
            String parameterMode = parameter.get("mode");
            String parameterType = parameter.get("type");

            if (parameterName == null || parameterMode == null || parameterType == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter not sufficiently configured.");
            }

            // ... Map the declared type of each parameter to the SQL type defined in java.sql.Types...
            int sqlType;
            try {
                Class sqlTypesClass = java.sql.Types.class;
                Field f = sqlTypesClass.getField(parameterType.toUpperCase());
                sqlType = (Integer)f.get(sqlTypesClass);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameter type.");
            } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to derive parameter type.");
            }

            // ... and select the correct Spring JDBC SqlParameter class according to the inbound mode.
            if (PARAMETER_MODE_IN.equalsIgnoreCase(parameterMode)) {
                declareParameter(new SqlParameter(parameterName, sqlType));
                // Remember to add this parameter to the internal list.
                inParameterNames.add(parameterName);
            } else if (PARAMETER_MODE_OUT.equalsIgnoreCase(parameterMode)) {
                declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(parameterName, sqlType));
            } else if (PARAMETER_MODE_INOUT.equalsIgnoreCase(parameterMode)) {
                declareParameter(new SqlInOutParameter(parameterName, sqlType));
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameter mode.");
            }
        }

        // Prepare the procedure call using the Spring JDBC StoredProcedure method.
        compile();
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to include only IN parameters
     * when the procedure is actually invoked and its results processed.
     *
     * @return Set<String> The set of IN only parameters
     */
    public Set<String> getInParameterNames() {
        return this.inParameterNames;
    }

    /**
     * This is the method that is called from the Camel flow to invoke
     * and execute the stored procedure, and return its results.
     *
     * @param body     The inbound Camel message body
     * @param exchange The Camel Exchange object
     *
     * @return Map<String, Object> A Map of out parameter names and their correspondent values.
     */
    @Handler
    public Map<String, Object> process(final String body, final Exchange exchange) {
        // Get all of the inbound headers so that we can obtain the parameter values.
        Map<String, Object> inParameters = exchange.getIn().getHeaders();

        // Unfortunately, there are other name/value pairs included in the payload...
        Set<String> inParameterNames = this.getInParameterNames();

        // ... so we need to filter those out...
        inParameters.keySet().retainAll(inParameterNames);

        // ... and then we can finally execute the procedure and return its results.
        return this.execute(inParameters);
    }
}
```

The SQL procedure I am using my Oracle database is as follows:

```
create or replace function greeting
  (name in varchar2)
   return varchar2 as
begin
   return 'Hello, ' || name || '!!!';
end;
/
```

When I am trying to run this example its just showing `Starting camel...` in console and not showing any kind of output.

Comment: Provide code snippet of your stored procedure. Presume that your procedure when executes in database is working as you desire.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Polppan...The code snippet of my store procedure is as below..                                                                create or replace function greeting
  (name in varchar2)
   return varchar2 as
begin
   return 'Hello, ' || name || '!!!';
end;
/

Comment: if you add another simple log route to the context that starts via a timer, does it print out?

Comment: Its not printing anything...@DakotaBrown